# Changing data dynamically for a series in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts, boxplot

I have a chart working fine with data in the options, when I leave the data empty for a series and try the below (so I can change the data depending on a click) it doesn't work, any ideas?

```
options.series[0].data = [35.00,35.91,36.82,37.73,38.64];
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you can also go with `series.setData()`. This will allow you to change the entire data of a particular series.

Here is the API [link](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData) for it.

Hope this will be of use for you.

Answer (score 11):

You can update the values dynamically as follows :

```
chart.series[0].setData([89,71,16,12,14]);
```

If you want to change both value and label, create an array of arrays:

```
chart.series[0].setData([['Apple',89], ['Orange',71], ['Banana',16], ['Grapes',12], ['Others',14]]);
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xjphws2g/) to update data on a button click.

Answer (score 5):

Eureka - needs nested square brackets so this below works..

```
options.series[0].data = [[35.00,35.91,36.82,37.73,38.64]];
```